# Not able to create Service Resource

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice

I a trying to create a service resource by putting resource type as *Technician* in a test class.

Like below:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> paramsList = new List<Map<String, Object>>();    
ServiceResource serviceResourceRecord 
                        = new ServiceResource(Name=ResourceName
                                           , ResourceType ='Technician'
                                           , RelatedRecordId=relatedUser.Id
                                           , IsActive=true);
insert serviceResourceRecord;
```

Getting below issue:

**System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Resource Type: bad value for restricted picklist field: Technician: [ResourceType]**

I tried checking allowed values in the pick list:

[image]

I am seeing *Technician* in the pick list of resource type:

[image]

How can I create *Technician* type resource through apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you manually create a ServiceResource and then query it you will find that resourcetype is set as 'T' not as 'Technincian' hence you need to pass 'T'which is a valid value for this picklist.

```
ServiceResource serviceResourceRecord 
                        = new ServiceResource(Name='ResourceName2'
                                           , ResourceType ='T'
                                           , RelatedRecordId=relatedUser.Id
                                           , IsActive=true);
insert serviceResourceRecord;
```